# Pick a random string from an array

Tags: java, eclipse

So I'm having a brain fart at the moment and can't figure out how to finish this part of the code:

```
String[] diceNumbers = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"};
String pickedNumber = (diceNumbers[new Random()]);
```

I saw this on another StackedOverflow past but I can't find it again.

I want it to be stored as a String variable so I can add it into another line of code because I'm using it in a Minecraft plugin

```
Bukkit.broadcastMessage(p.getName() + "has rolled a" + pickedNumber);
```

is what I am trying to do

Comment: what do you want to get in the end?

Comment: The random number must be in the range of 0 to array length - 1;  Now you can search for that.

Comment: The diceNumber.length part

Comment: `diceNumbers.length` ?

Comment: @ScaryWombat yes. That is what I have been doing so it get a random number within the length of the array
Edit: Zheka just answered it :) Thanks for the help

Comment: Why don't you do this:
make random number like this `r.nextInt(5) + 1` to make a random number between 1 and 6. and put it directly in your string

Comment: "_That is what I have been doing so it get a random number within the length of the array_", so you had a solution from the start ?

Comment: @AxelH Techinally yes but I completely forgot how to do it and couldn't find the answer anywhere

Comment: @ScaryWombat if you are going to mark a post as a duplicate, you should seriously provide the link to the original post

Comment: @secon19665 If you are going to criticize me, you should seriously look at the link at the top of this page which links to the original post.  Strange eh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [ThreadLocalRandom](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html):

```
String pickedNumber = diceNumbers[ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(diceNumbers.length)];
```

Comment: It would be nice to explain why this would be a solution.

Comment: This just answered my question.
I have been using
```String pickedNumber = (diceNumbers[new Random().nextInt(diceNumbers.length)]);```

Comment: @secon19665 This is semantically the same but `ThreadLocalRandom` is generally faster than creating a `Random` instance every time

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov I'm only using it once in the plugin that I am making so it doesn't fully matter to me. I don't see why people are downvoting your answer because it answers my question haha. I will be accepting your answer!